# Circle Packing - Average distance between a random point in a circle and the second, third, fourth, ... closest circle centre

Tags: geometry, circles, packing-problem

I am currently working on the following problem (see also the example drawing): Suppose I have, for example, a hexagonal circle packing or a square arrangement. And we randomly place a point in a circle in this arrangement. Is there a formula to (relatively) easily calculate what the average distance of a random point to the second, third, fourth, ... closest circle centre within the arrangement is? In addition, I am also interested in the problem if there is no infinite plane, but if, for example, the 7 circles shown in the example drawing would be the only circles in my circle packing arrangement.

I'm not a circle packing expert at all, but I have the feeling that such a problem might have been investigated before?

Alternatively, I could calculate it with a computer program. However, this would of course be quite inefficient? Nevertheless, I would also be grateful if someone knows code that already calculates this problem.

[image: Example drawing]

Comment: Have you heard about the concept of KNN (Kth Nearest Neighbour)  ?

Comment: Yeah, I've heard of that :) Thanks for the tip! If I want to calculate it with a computer program, I can probably use code snippets from kth-NN programs. Mathematically, though, I'm personally still without inspiration in terms of the average distance of a random point in a circle to the second, third, ... nearest circle centre.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The issue can be simplified by looking at the distribution of distances from variable point $M$ to only three points which are the vertices of an equilateral triangle like $C,A,E$. Moreover, one can consider at first that $M$ can be anywhere in triangle $CAE$, constraining it in a second step to stay inside the circle centered in $G$ which is the incircle of triangle $CAE$.

The distribution of distances can be treated using barycentric coordinates. Having this distribution, it is easy to obtain its mean.

Remark: the distribution of distances with respect to the "complementary" triangle $BDF$ is clearly identical to the distribution with respect to triangle $CAE$.

If I have some time in the coming days, I will attempt to make the calculations.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is a very valuable hint. Lets say I am interested in every case possible, e.g. only circles centered in AB, ABG, ABGF and so on exist; up to infinity. I haven't done the calculations yet, but I think your hint regarding decomposing the problem into symmetric parts could indeed be the solution for every case? I need to read up on barycentric coordinates and geometry. In the case of 4 circles centered in ABGF one could draw two lines through BF and AG to derive the symmetric cases?

Comment: For your last question mark, I think so.